# Drag and drop spelling game styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am creating a word spelling, **drag and drop game**. When the letters are dragged onto the words in the table, a style is triggered depending on whether the spelling is right or wrong. If it is **right** the **word fades away** to reveal the picture behind. If it is **wrong** the letters **glow red** as set by the style.

My problem is that the letters stay red throughout the rest of the game, meaning the image behind cannot be completed because you it wont allow you to spell the words glowing red. I need the style to go when the next turn happens and allow you to have another go at spelling that word, can anyone help me with this?

Here is the script that triggers the CSS...

```
$(".drop").droppable({ 

hoverClass: 'drophover',
drop: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    guesses[word].push($(ui.draggable).attr('data-letter'));

    console.log(guesses);

    if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
        if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow2");


        } else {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow");

        }
    }
}
});
```

Here is the CSS for this is...

```
.wordglow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 20px 0px 10px 5px #ff0000;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 5px #ff0000;

}

.drop.wordglow2 {

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 5px #22ff22;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 5px #22ff22;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;


}
```

I have tried this to enable the wrong answer to be spellable again..

```
$('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow").removeAttr('disabled');;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the class on the `activate` event. So when an object is glowing red, the red disappears when you start dragging it to a next position again!

```
$(".drop").droppable({ 
    hoverClass: 'drophover',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        word = $(this).data('word');

        guesses[word].push($(ui.draggable).attr('data-letter'));

        console.log(guesses);

        if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
            if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {
                $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow2");
            } else {
                $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow");
            }
        }
    },

    // this event is triggered when a draggable object is activated
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        word = $(this).data('word');

        // try to remove the class
        $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').removeClass('wordglow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't this bring back the right answers as well though? @Tim S.

Comment: Also, even though the words style leaves on the next turn, it still won't allow you to spell it, so the problem of clearing the grid is still there. @Tim S.

Comment: @IronSpoon yes it would. In that case you can remove just one class instead of both. What do you mean with "it still won't allow you to spell it"?